# How to add a slash or why it isn't added?

Tags: .htaccess, url, anchor

I am currently using Bootstrap to add an accordion function to a jobs page on a new website. Everything works fine, however when I click to view a specific accordion to display the listing, the URL only works like this: `website/jobs#developer` and not like this: `website/jobs/#developer` which would look a lot more professional on job boards and maintain what we have on our current site.

I don't want to have to go back to every link distributed and remove the slash. I am attaching what I have done in my htaccess but I am not sure its is affected by it. Please help!

```xml
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    ErrorDocument 404 /views/errors/404.php
    RewriteRule ^(jobs|Jobs|JOBS)$ views/jobs.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The rewrite rule will not match a trailing slash

> ^(jobs|Jobs|JOBS)$

This rewrite rule *will not* match a url with a trailing slash, it means:

```
^ # start of match
jobs|Jobs|JOBS # One of these strings
$ # End of match
```

To have it match urls with a trailing slash, that needs to be in the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(jobs|Jobs|JOBS)/?$
                             ^ A slash
                              ^ 0 or 1 times - i.e. optional
```

### Professional urls?

> website/jobs/#developer which would look a lot more professional on job boards

Unrelated to the question, but the presence or absence of a trailing slash doesn't have any bearing on how professional a url looks.

Comment: I completely understood. My reference to fear is in respect to hurting others feelings. Folks are way to sensitive today and I just don't have time for that.
Thank you again!